# Problem loading google map directions layer from javascript function in HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a page with a Google map on it and an unordered list of places taken from a nearby search request. 99% of it works fine but I cannot for the life of me get links to work in the innerHTML of the list items.

```
function callback(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

                document.getElementById("ulPlaces").innerHTML = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                    var placeRequest = {
                        placeId: results[i].place_id
                    };

                    service.getDetails(placeRequest, function(resultDetails, status) {
                        if (status == 'OK') {

                            placeWebsite = resultDetails.website;
                            placePhoneNumber = resultDetails.formatted_phone_number;
                        }
                    });


                    var node = document.createElement("li");
                    node.setAttribute("class", "liPlaces");
                    node.setAttribute("id", results[i].place_id);

                    node.innerHTML = '<img class="imgPlaces" src="' + results[i].icon + '" alt="" /><h4 class="h4Places">' + results[i].name + '</h4><p>Open: ' + results[i].opening_hours.open_now + ' | Rating: ' + results[i].rating + '</p><p><input type="button" onclick="loadDirections(' + results[i].geometry.location + ')" value="Directions" /> | <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href=tel:' + placePhoneNumber + ';" value="Telephone" /> | <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href=' + placeWebsite + ';" value="Website" /></p>';


                    document.getElementById("ulPlaces").appendChild(node);


                    /*
                    infoWindow.setPosition(results[i].geometry.location);
                    infoWindow.setContent(results[i].name);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    */

                    var image = {
                        url: results[i].icon,
                        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: image,
                        title: results[i].name,
                        position: results[i].geometry.location
                    });

                    marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) { 
                        return function() {
                            //if( prev_infowindow ) {
                            //   prev_infowindow.close();
                            //}

                            window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(results[i].place_id).offsetTop)

                            //loadDirections(results[i].geometry.location)

                            //prev_infowindow = infoWindow;
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            }
        }

        function loadDirections(end){

            var path = {
                origin: pos,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: 'WALKING'
            };

            directionsService.route(path, function(resultDirections, statusRoute) {
                if (statusRoute == 'OK') {
                    directionsRenderer.setDirections(resultDirections);
                }
            });
        }
```

The callback function is the search query return. There's a for loop to iterate through them and a request for more specific details (website/phone number). It then creates 'var node' and adds class and id attributes and some innerHTML.

If I take the code out of the innerHTML it works. There's a click function attached to the marker where loadDirections is commented out. That call works, just not the one in the innerHTML.

The buttons to make a telephone call and navigate to the place website might as well be dead buttons too.

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: is `onclick="loadDirections(' + results[i].geometry.location + ')"` the code you're referring to that *doesn't work*? If you inspect that element with your browsers developer tools, what does the value in `onclick=""` look like? something like `onclick="loadDirections([object Object])"` perhaps?

Comment: Hello Bravo, thanks for the reply. 

Yes, that's the one. It returns a JSON object with lat/long for a Google Map marker. The object being returned is being returned correctly, the commented out call to the function a few lines below works without problem.

If I call the function both before and after 'node.innerHTML = ""' it works fine, it's only when I move the function to the onclick event it fails!

Comment: *If you inspect that element with your browsers developer tools, what does the value in onclick="" look like?*